# Gradle Errors in Android Studio for Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to build my app and I am getting below error, not sure, how to resolve it

```
1) Error:(49, 91) error: cannot find symbol variable BOOKMARKS_URI
2) Error:(56, 94) error: cannot find symbol variable BookmarkColumns
3) Error:(3780, 27) error: cannot find symbol method setLatestEventInfo(Context,String,String,PendingIntent)
```

Any idea, how to get over it?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Marshmallow removed the support for the bookmarks

> **Browser Bookmark Changes**
>
> This release removes support for global bookmarks. The
>   android.provider.Browser.getAllBookmarks() and
>   android.provider.Browser.saveBookmark() methods are now removed.
>   Likewise, the READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS and WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS
>   permissions are removed. If your app targets Android 6.0 (API level
>   23) or higher, don't access bookmarks from the global provider or use
>   the bookmark permissions. Instead, your app should store bookmarks
>   data internally.
>
> Reference
>   http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser

Comment: Note that this is not unique to Android Studio- if you had updated your app to compile with API 23 in Eclipse, you would see the same errors.

Comment: @Tanis.7x - Thanks Tanis, I agree, but do I really need Android studio to compile apk for Marshmallow ? is Gradle required ?

Comment: @user45678 think the opposite: do you really need this api? They have removed it for a reason

Comment: @user45678 Unfortunately it's not an issue with Gradle or Android Studio. You can't use global bookmarks with API 23 because it was removed by Google.

Comment: @TimCastelijns - Agreed, i may remove, but there is also another huge impact with Https classes. I am using Https classes and they have removed that too. They suggested, if i want to use, i will have to have gradle file and and add exception to it, for which i require Android Studio, can't Gradle compilation be done with Eclipse ?

Comment: @user45678 I don't know. But you should migrate to android studio asap anyway

Comment: is this any alternative way to achieve this in marshmallow?

Answer (score 0):

Use the compiler version 21.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/core.jar')
}
```